# How to make nodejs-Express server treat the http requests as https requests

Tags: express, http-proxy

I have node express server which is on http.
This server proxies requests to another target which accepts only https.

I tried using https.createServer but it dint work.

Question is how do I make express treat http requests as https.

```
//route to get the projects list
app.get("/getprojects", (req, res) => {
    var projects = ["project1", "project2", "project3"];
    res.send({ projects });
});

//error handling
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).send("Sorry can't find that!");
});

https
    .createServer(
        {
            key: fs.readFileSync("./cert/server.key"),
            cert: fs.readFileSync("./cert/server.cert"),
        },
        app
    )
    .listen(port, () => console.log(`HTTPS server is running on port ${port}!`));
```

Comment: This question isn't making a lot of sense.  Your server either listens for http connections or https connections.  If you want your server to listen for incoming https connections, then you use `https.createServer()` and you would typically listen on the default port for https which is 443 (unless all your https URLs specify a custom port number).

Comment: You can't make Express treat http as https.  You can have an http server that does nothing but redirect to your https server (to force all users to use https).  But, an http server is an http server, not an https server.  And, likewise an https server is an https server, not an http server.  You can't make one act like the other.  You are either using TLS for security or not.